# How to work with rabbitTemplate receiveAndReply

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have just started experimenting with Spring and rabbitMQ.
I would like to create a microsevice infrastructure with rabbit and spring,
I have been following [Spring boot tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/)

But it is very simplistic. As well I am looking at the documentation ([springs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.3.5.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html#request-reply), [Rabbit](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-java.html)) for how to create an RPC, i understand the Rabbits approach, but i would like to leverage Spring template to save me the boilerplate.

I just cant seem to understand where to register the reciveAndReplay callback at.

I tried doing this:

sending

> ```
>     System.out.println("Sending message...");
>     Object convertSendAndReceive = rabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceive("spring-boot", "send and recive: sent");
>     System.out.println("GOT " + convertSendAndReceive); //is null
> ```

receiving

> ```
> @Component
> public class Receiver {
> @Autowired
> RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;
> public void receiveMessage(String message) {
>     this.rabbitTemplate.receiveAndReply("spring-boot", (Message)->{
>         return "return this statement";
>     });
> }
> }
> ```

But its not a big surprise this doesn't work the message is received but nothing comes back. I assume that this needs to be registered somewhere in the factory/template at the bean creation level but i don't seem to understand where and sadly the documentation is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

First, please use the [Spring AMQP Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest_ga/reference/html/).

You would generally use a `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` wired with a POJO listener for RPC.

The template `receiveAndReply` method is intended for "scheduled" server-side RPC - i.e. only receive (and reply) when you want to, rather than whenever a message arrives in the queue. It does not block waiting for a message.

If you want to use `receiveAndReply()`, there's a [test case that illustrates it](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/test/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplateIntegrationTests.java#L827).

**EDIT**:

This code...

```
    this.template.convertAndSend(ROUTE, "test");
```

sends a message to the queue.

This code...

```
    this.template.setQueue(ROUTE);
    boolean received = this.template.receiveAndReply(new ReceiveAndReplyMessageCallback() {

        @Override
        public Message handle(Message message) {
            message.getMessageProperties().setHeader("foo", "bar");
            return message;
        }
    });
```

Receives a message and from that queue; adds a header and returns the same messsage to the reply queue. `received` will be false if there was no message to receive (and reply to).

This code:

```
    Message receive = this.template.receive();
```

receives the reply.

This test is a bit contrived because the reply is sent to the same queue as the request. We can't use `sendAndReceive()` on the client side in this test because the thread would block waiting for the reply (and we need to execute the `receiveAndReply()`).

[Another test in that class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/test/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplateIntegrationTests.java#L996) has a more realistic example where it does the `sendAndReceive()`s on different threads and the `receiveAndReply()`s on the main thread.

Note that that test uses a listener container on the client side for replies; that is generally no longer needed since the rabbit broker now supports [direct reply-to](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/amqp.html#direct-reply-to).

`receiveAndReply()` was added for symmetry - in most cases, people use a listener container and listener adapter for server-side RPC.

Comment: So basically the receiveAndReply does not really live to its name. what you advice on doing is to just use the receiver class to do something and send back a message with the correlation id?

Comment: ? ... It __does__ live up to its name just fine if there's a message available. As you can see from those tests, it works as expected. Howecer, it's an active, not passive, operation. For passive RPC, use the listener container and listener adapter.

Comment: I would assume that "receiveAndReply" would receive a message, and then instantly replay to that message, maybe i lack understanding of the terminology as i am super new to this or maybe i need to read some more about this because its still very much unclear on how to use receiveAndReplay even from the documentation and your explanation.  (how is a callback considered an "active" operation...)

Comment: That is exactly what the test I pointed you too does; I'll edit the answer with some more clarity - we're obviously not connecting on terminology. The callback is passive but the `receiveAndReply` has to be invoked by your code (that's what I mean by active).